# Add to cart button redirects to nothing(Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart, spree

In branch '3-0-stable'(Spree), the **Add to Cart** button redirects to a page which doesn't exist, without adding the product to the cart.
It redirect to orders/populate path but then:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is an error occurred. And your setting might not allowing throwing exception in front. Maybe because this is not in development environment.

Anyway, `order/populate` path does exist on `3-0-stable` Spree. Please look in [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/frontend/config/routes.rb#L22) and [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb#L40).

Comment: It seems I'm stupid, I was looking in 3-3-stable while using 3-0. Thanks anyway for help:)